# Getting the device language from iOS and Android in the same format

Tags: android, ios, iso-639-2

My team is building an app for Android and iOS. The application receives several notifications from the server, in various forms like push notifications and UI popups.

In order to send the messages in the right language, I would like the apps in both platforms to send me the device language *in the same format*.

For example, English can be `en` or `eng` or even `English`, but it must be the same for both devices.

Is there a language name format supported by both iOS and Android? If so, what are the calls for the device language in both platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, [iPhone's IETF BCP 47 language codes can be converted to Android's ISO-639-2 codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085570/how-to-convert-ietf-bcp-47-language-identifier-to-iso-639-2).

I will accept both inputs in their native form and convert iPhone's BCP 47 to ISO-639-2 on the server side.

Answer (score 4):

Android:

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()       ---> en      
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language()   ---> eng 
Locale.getDefault().getCountry()        ---> US 
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Country()    ---> USA 
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry() ---> United States 
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName()    ---> English (United States)
```

iOS

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject]; // ---> en
```

documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/ChoosingLocalizations.html

So you can use "en" for English. 
There must be something available for ios to get the full language name but I haven't used it before.