# How to convert IETF BCP 47 language identifier to ISO-639-2?

Tags: python, ios, iso-639-2, ietf-bcp-47

I am writing a server API for an iOS application. As a part of the initialization process, the app should send the phone interface language to server via an API call.

The problem is that Apple uses something called [IETF BCP 47 language identifier](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47) in its [`NSLocale preferredLanguages` function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_18).

The returned values have different lengths (e.g. `[aa, ab, ace, ach, ada, ady, ae, af, afa, afh, agq, ...]`, and I found very few parsers that can convert this code to a proper language identifier.

I would like to use the more common [ISO-639-2 three-letters language identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes), which is ubiquitous, has many parsers in many languages, and has a standard, 3-letter representation of languages.

**How can I convert a IETF BCP 47 language identifier to ISO-639-2 three-letters language identifier, preferably in Python?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BCP 47 identifiers start with a 2 letter ISO 639-1 *or* 3 letter 639-2, 639-3 or 639-5 language code; see the [RFC 5646 Syntax section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646#section-2.1):

> ```
> Language-Tag  = langtag             ; normal language tags
>               / privateuse          ; private use tag
>               / grandfathered       ; grandfathered tags
>
> langtag       = language
>                 ["-" script]
>                 ["-" region]
>                 *("-" variant)
>                 *("-" extension)
>                 ["-" privateuse]
>
> language      = 2*3ALPHA            ; shortest ISO 639 code
>                 ["-" extlang]       ; sometimes followed by
>                                     ; extended language subtags
>               / 4ALPHA              ; or reserved for future use
>               / 5*8ALPHA            ; or registered language subtag
> ```

I don't expect Apple to use the `privateuse` or `grandfathered` forms, so you can assume that you are looking at ISO 639-1, ISO 639-2, ISO 639-3 or ISO 639-5 language codes here. Simply map the 2-letter ISO-639-1 codes to 3-letter ISO 639-* codes.

You can use the [`pycountry` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry) for this:

```
import pycountry

lang = pycountry.languages.get(alpha2=two_letter_code)
three_letter_code = lang.terminology
```

Demo:

```
>>> import pycountry
>>> lang = pycountry.languages.get(alpha2='aa')
>>> lang.terminology
u'aar'
```

where the *terminology* form is the preferred 3-letter code; there is also a *bibliography* form which differs only for 22 entries. See [ISO 639-2 *B and T codes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-2#B_and_T_codes). The package doesn't include entries from ISO 639-5 however; that list overlaps and conflicts with 639-2 in places and I don't think Apple uses such codes at all.

Comment: Thanks! It would make parsing a whole lot easier. Do you have a reference to that fact please?

Comment: @AdamMatan: added the RFC references for you.

Comment: 639 is not just 639-1 and 639-2. A 3-character iso 639 language code can be 639-3.

Comment: @FabianKessler: right, and there is also 639-5, although that list is rather sparse. `pycountry` doesn't include it.

Answer (score 2):

From [RFC5646/BCP47](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47#section-2.1):

```
Language-Tag  = langtag             ; normal language tags
              / privateuse          ; private use tag
              / grandfathered       ; grandfathered tags

langtag       = language
                ["-" script]
                ["-" region]
                *("-" variant)
                *("-" extension)
                ["-" privateuse]

language      = 2*3ALPHA            ; shortest ISO 639 code
                ["-" extlang]       ; sometimes followed by
                                    ; extended language subtags
              / 4ALPHA              ; or reserved for future use
              / 5*8ALPHA            ; or registered language subtag

privateuse    = "x" 1*("-" (1*8alphanum))

grandfathered = irregular           ; non-redundant tags registered
              / regular             ; during the RFC 3066 era
```

It looks like the first segment of most BCP-47 codes should be valid ISO-639 codes though they might not be the three letter variants.  A BCP-47 language code has a few variants that are not ISO-639 codes - namely those beginning with `x-` or `i-` as well as a number of legacy codes that match the `grandfathered` portion of the grammar:

```
irregular     = "en-GB-oed"         ; irregular tags do not match
              / "sgn-BE-FR"         ; also includes i- prefixed codes
              / "sgn-BE-NL"
              / "sgn-CH-DE"

regular       = "art-lojban"        ; these tags match the 'langtag'
              / "cel-gaulish"       ; production, but their subtags
              / "no-bok"            ; are not extended language
              / "no-nyn"            ; or variant subtags: their meaning
              / "zh-guoyu"          ; is defined by their registration
              / "zh-hakka"          ; and all of these are deprecated
              / "zh-min"            ; in favor of a more modern
              / "zh-min-nan"        ; subtag or sequence of subtags
              / "zh-xiang"
```

A good start would be something like the following:

```
def extract_iso_code(bcp_identifier):
    language, _ = bcp_identifier.split('-', 1)
    if 2 <= len(language) <=3:
        # this is a valid ISO-639 code or is grandfathered
    else:
        # handle non-ISO codes
        raise ValueError(bcp_identifier)
```

Conversion from the 2-character variant to the 3-character variant should be easy enough to handle since the mapping is well known.